# Ayuda Como concatenar en SQL SERVER 2012 un campo nvarchar y un tipo datetime

Tags: sql-server-2012

Buenos dias queria saber si pueden ayudar con la consulta siguiente quiero concatenar un campo NVARCHAR con uno DATETIME este es mi codigo

```
SELECT CONVERT (NVARCHAR(10), u.COMPROBANT)+' '+'del '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),u.FECHA_TRS, 103) AS 'Comprobante #',m.COMPROBANT FROM
MOVIM AS m
LEFT JOIN ARTICULO AS a ON a.COD_ART = m.COD_ART 
LEFT JOIN BODEGA AS b ON b.COD_BODEGA = m.COD_BODEGA
LEFT JOIN T_UNI AS tu ON tu.COD_UNI = a.COD_UNI
LEFT JOIN USOMAT AS u ON u.COMPROBANT = m.COMPROBANT WHERE  u.FECHA_TRS IS NULL
```

pero el resultado es que no me concatena si no que me manda todos NULL
asi como lo muestra en la imagen

[image: Como podrán apreciar el campo Comprante # es el concatenado]

Answer (score 0):

La función de convert no lo está realizando. Intenta con [cast](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_cast.asp)

```
SELECT u.COMPROBANT +' '+'del '+ CAST(ISNULL(u.FECHA_TRS, '') AS NVARCHAR(10)) AS 'Comprobante #',m.COMPROBANT FROM
MOVIM AS m
LEFT JOIN ARTICULO AS a ON a.COD_ART = m.COD_ART 
LEFT JOIN BODEGA AS b ON b.COD_BODEGA = m.COD_BODEGA
LEFT JOIN T_UNI AS tu ON tu.COD_UNI = a.COD_UNI
LEFT JOIN USOMAT AS u ON u.COMPROBANT = m.COMPROBANT WHERE  u.FECHA_TRS IS NULL
```

Pero sí es necesario que asignes algún formato de fecha en especifico, continua con [convert](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Ahora, sí el valor de tu fecha es null, es necesario validarlo con [isnull()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: el problema que el comprante no solo contiene numero si no que tambien con tiene la palabra 'SALDO-ALTA'  lo que quiero que muestre es SALDO-ALTA + la  fecha

Comment: COMPROBANT no es necesario castearlo porque ya es varchar. la cuestion es la validación de tu where porque estas consultando las fechas nullas

Comment: como le pongo para cuando encuentre fecha null me ponga vacio siempre en la concatenacion

Comment: validando con ISNULL()

Comment: aun con el isnull en  select me manda el campo null @Aaron Romero

Comment: revisa de nuevo, trata con validar primero y despues castear. Esas son las herramientas que necesitas